# How to detect programs on secondary drive after a fresh Windows installation

Tags: windows-10, filesystems, windows-installation

Following an SSD failure, I reinstalled Windows 10 on a new SSD. Since the majority of my program installations were on my larger HDD, I still have the files and programs from before the failure.

However, Windows doesn't seem to be aware of them (context menus, search bars, etc.) If I manually navigate to SecondDrive/Programs/program.exe and run it, the program will still run in the majority of cases.

My understanding is that the registry (stored on SSD C:) was in charge of this, and is now gone. I also think that there are programs which may no longer work because of this - some reinstallations might be necessary (which I'm fine with).

That being said, is there a way to tell Windows to scan for programs and applications on another drive?

Comment: are you kinda asking to see the list of the previously installed programs or you're asking on how to reinstall those same programs?

Comment: @Antz I'm asking for a way to get Windows to 'scan' and 'recognize' existing executables on another drive

Comment: @fpscolin - **There isn't a mechanism to do that.**  You would have to reinstall those applications.  If those applications don't actually require you to install them to function, simply running their executable, will start the program.  If you want the application in the start menu you can either pin a shortcut to the executable, or reinstall the application and that will be done for you by the installer.

Comment: @Ramhound I was afraid of that. Thank you for confirming my suspicions.